# Cсчитывание данных которые водятся с клавиатуры и их сумирование

Tags: c#, .net

Возникает ошибка FormatException. Подскажите, как исправить?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("введите в строчку параметры через пробел");
        int[] mas = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(Summ.Summa(mas));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Summ
{

    public static int Summa(params int[] args)
    {
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            z += args[i];
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что во введённой строке?

Comment: Слова через пробел.

Comment: СЛОВА?? То есть вы вводите

> один два пятнадцать ноль

и ожидаете, что `int.Parse` из превратит в числа?

Comment: нет, не ожидаю,просто не знаю как исправить это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вводите числа (цифрами, а не прописью). Разбор слов — сложная задача. Если в задании нужен именно разбор слов, вам придётся постараться.
2. Скажите спасибо человеку, который написал вам изящный ввод чисел с LINQ. Прислушивайтесь к его советам.

**Обновление**

Ох. Если разбор слов, вам придётся постараться. В любом случае, всё не так уж и страшно. Функцию, которая по числу прописью даёт `int`, вам придётся написать самому. Что-то наподобие такого: http://pastebin.com/aUnzCKhj Это набросок на скорую руку, там многого нет, например, разбора чисел от 11 до 20, код не понимает числа «двести», «триста» и т. д. Но от него можно отталкиваться.

Comment: 1.Код я нашел, пытаюсь разобраться, чисто с любопытства и чисто для себя,что бы что-то извлечь из этого.
2.Нужен разбор слов.Не скажете в каком направлении стоит копать?

Comment: В общем, если это учебное задание, то это хорошее, сложное задание. Удачи вам!